# How to completely turn a gas into positive or negative ions

Tags: electrons, atoms, protons, ionization-energy

How would I completely turn a gas into positive ions?
How would I completely turn a gas into negative ions?

Could I simply have a gas in a sealed chamber with an ion generator inside with the power source coming from the outside of said sealed chamber?

Comment: Where does the extra charge go? Do you mean a fully-ionized plasma? Or how will you overcome the Coulomb repulsion of all the like charges?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No one produces a pure gas of ions, because there is no practical way to force
separation of charge that would survive collisions between molecules,
and no way to  hold such a gas against repulsion of the like charges.
The only pure ions available for experimentation are in VERY dilute
gasses (vacuum, basically) or in atomic or molecular beams, where tricks are used
to separate out ions with a particular charge-to-mass ratio.

Those tricks require the ions to be in motion, thus commonly make
a beam of ions.  The possibility exists of holding ions for long periods
of time in a cyclotron (which directs the beam of  ions in a circular path).

Small groups of  ions can be held by laser traps, but gas-like random
motion is not really happening there.

Answer (score 0):

What type of gas do you want to ionize? 
Suppose it is Hydrogen. Keep it in chamber in apply potential greater than the ionizing potential of hydrogen. Most of it will be ionized but as soon as you remove the ions out of chamber or remove the applies potential it will again become hydrogen.

Similarly if you take helium you will have to apply potential which takes out its two electrons but it can stay ionized inside chamber and not outside it.

You might think of bombarding a gas with let say electrons. For example you bombard chlorine with electrons. It will convert the chlorine into negative ions but partially and temporarily. As soon as you stop bombarding, chlorine atoms will start rejecting electrons due to Coulombic repulsion effects.

All it gives is that you cannot take positive ions from a gas and bombard your enemy with it to kill him. And for producing electrons you don't simply need a gas.